# modification of DJB2 hash function

Tags: c, hash

I use `sendto` as below to send some text over a UDP socket.

```
char *buf = "hello";
sendto(s, buf, strlen(buf)+1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slength);
```

I would like to add a hash value at the end of the string. I am planning to use [DJB2 function on this link](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html).

But that function generates a too long hash value (261238937 = for "hello") as I will convert it into string and will extend the char array 9 more elements. Therefore, I am planning to replace `unsigned long` with `uint16_t` which generates a shorter (12441) value.

```
uint16_t hash(unsigned char *str){
    uint16_t long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    return hash;
}
```

I wonder if that modification would cause any problem on the algorithm? And how is it possible to make the code "endian-proof"?

Comment: Yes, truncating the hash value to the lower 16 bits decreases entropy. Why not take it modulo a sufficiently large prime number instead?

Comment: basically, now is easier to have a collision. It's possible, see `htols()` and `ntohl()` man pages.

Comment: Do you need to send a decimal string representation of the number?

Comment: @H2CO3: do you mean I should modulo the return value, `return hash % 997`?

Comment: @larsmans:I was thinking to use `snprintf` to add hash value to the `buf`. sould you suggest me to use a different method that I can carry the info by less bytes?

Comment: @sven, basically, yes.

Comment: @sven: make sure the hash value has a fixed width (e.g. `uint32_t`), then append the big-endian version of it to the buffer directly. A `uint32_t` takes only four bytes.